# Terrafrom change a map

Tags: terraform

Do you know how I can change this:

```
{
  "ax-lb-mtls-01" = {
    "ax-lb-mtls-01/forwarding-subnet-01" = "10.100.0.203"
    "ax-lb-mtls-01/forwarding-subnet-02" = "10.100.0.205"
  }
  "ax-lb-mtls-02" = {
    "ax-lb-mtls-02/forwarding-subnet-01" = "10.100.0.204"
    "ax-lb-mtls-02/forwarding-subnet-02" = "10.100.0.206"
  }
}
```

into this:

```
{
    "ax-lb-mtls-01/forwarding-subnet-01" = "10.100.0.203"
    "ax-lb-mtls-01/forwarding-subnet-02" = "10.100.0.205"
    "ax-lb-mtls-02/forwarding-subnet-01" = "10.100.0.204"
    "ax-lb-mtls-02/forwarding-subnet-02" = "10.100.0.206"
}
```

I would like to transform this to use by another module.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
merge(values(local.input)...)
```